# Show/Hide Div's via <a> | Save Scrollbar | Save State

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

:)

I want to code a Forum where you can switch the divs (Sub Forums) which are shown via `<a>` tags.

I found this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/showhide-element/

And it works okay for the start, but sadly after I click on the link my scrollbar jumps to the top, I'd love to have it stay where it was before the click event. How can I achieve that? :)

Also when I refresh the whole process gets resettet (foo is always visible after refresh), can I somehow set variables so it remembers on which button we currently are and then, on a refresh, stays on that decision? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the href attribute of anchor tag

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">toggle</a>
```

Comment: Could you possibly tell me how I can also save the state so if I do a real refresh it jumps right into the before picked buttons selection? :)

Comment: Go through the link  http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_bookmark